# Netty multi threading per connection

Tags: multithreading, netty

I am new to netty. I would like to develop a server which aims at receiving requests from possibly few(say Max is of 2) clients. But each client will be sending many requests to server continuously. Server has to process such requests and respond to client. So, here I assume that even though if I configure multiple worker threds,it may not be useful as there are only 2 active connections. Worker thread again block till it process and respond to client. So, please let me know how to handle these type of problems.
If I use threadpoolexecutor in worker thread to process both clients requests in multi threaded manner, will it be efficient? Or if it cane achieved through netty framework, plz let me know how to do this?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly: your clients (2) will send many messages, each of them implying an answear as quickly as possible from the server.

2 options can be seen:

1. The answear process is short time (short enough to not be an isssue for the rate you want to reach, meaning 1 thread is able to answear as fast as you need for 1 client): then you can stay with the standard threads from Netty (1 worker thread for 1 client at a time) set up in the server bootstrap. This is the shortest path.
2. The answear process is not short time enough (the rate will be terrible, for instance because there is a "long time" process, such as blocking call, database access, file writing, ...): then you can add a thread pool (a group) in the Netty pipeline for you ChannelHandler doing such blocking/long process.

Here is an extract of the API documentation taken from ChannelPipeline:
http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html

```
// Tell the pipeline to run MyBusinessLogicHandler's event handler methods
// in a different thread than an I/O thread so that the I/O thread is not blocked by
// a time-consuming task.
// If your business logic is fully asynchronous or finished very quickly, you don't
// need to specify a group.
pipeline.addLast(group, "handler", new MyBusinessLogicHandler());
```

Comment: I have implemented DefaultEventExecutorGroup and added my handler to run under this group to pipe line as mentioned. Just added S.O.P to print thread name and Thread.sleep(2000) to see thread name and whether parallel threads are running and send 3 messages to server from one client. But its always showing same thread number for all 3 messages at server end. If I added threadpoolexecutor in my handler and dispatch messages to threadpoolexecutor, its running in parallel. Can I go with thread pool executor framework? will there be any difference? plz help...

Answer (score 0):

just add a ChannelHandler with a special EventExecutorGroup to the ChannelPipeline. For example UnorderedThreadPoolEventExecutor ([src](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/UnorderedThreadPoolEventExecutor.html)).

something like this.

```
UnorderedThreadPoolEventExecutor executorGroup = ...;
pipeline.addLast(executorGroup, new MyChannelHandler());
```